# Homebrew python formula pip installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, homebrew, setuptools

The Homebrew python formula says it installs pip & setuptools, but pip isn't in my path, and the following find doesn't return any results:

```
sudo find / -name pip -type f
```

How can I get pip & setuptools to work on my machine?  It's running OS X 10.11.1.

**Update**
The output for `brew info python` is:

```
python: stable 2.7.10 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2 (5902 files, 92M) *
  Built from source
From:     https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/python.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: openssl ✔
Recommended: readline ✔, sqlite ✔, gdbm ✔
Optional: homebrew/dupes/tcl-tk ✘, berkeley-db4 ✘
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--with-berkeley-db4
    Build with berkeley-db4 support
--with-poll
    Enable select.poll, which is not fully implemented on OS X (https://bugs.python.org/issue5154)
--with-quicktest
    Run `make quicktest` after the build (for devs; may fail)
--with-tcl-tk
    Use Homebrew's Tk instead of OS X Tk (has optional Cocoa and threads support)
--without-gdbm
    Build without gdbm support
--without-readline
    Build without readline support
--without-sqlite
    Build without sqlite support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See:     https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps python` to symlink these to /Applications.
```

I ran `brew linkapps python` as per the instructions above.

Comment: What is the output of `brew info python`?

Comment: @bfontaine I added the output in an edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip by default, so you may have pip already.

SetupTools -- Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and un-install Python packages

Please look, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: I'm worried about installing pip & SetupTools outside of homebrew, if homebrew says that it has already installed them.  Any reason why pip wouldn't be installed when homebrew says it should be?